# mcrypt_decrypt, openssl_decrypt and 0x06065064 EVP_DecryptFinal error

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I have a problem with the `openssl_decrypt` function.

Example code:

```
// mcrypt
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);

// OpenSSL
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

The `mcrypt_decrypt` function works fine. But `openssl_decrypt` returns `FALSE` and the following error:

> error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt

The key is 32 bytes long and the iv 16 bytes.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: It is best not to use mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt had many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003.. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption), it is being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 8):

The solution to the problem is `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` and `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`:

```
$decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

Comment: Absolute lifesaver.